# Relocating intermediate pointers during realloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, realloc, dangling-pointer

> Suppose if I have an allocated chunk of memory and an intermediate
>   pointer points to some location in the allocated chunk. If I change
>   the size of the memory by using `realloc()`, which may relocate the
>   whole chunk with the new size. Is there any way by which I can
>   relocate the old pointers too?

Example code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    int *q;
    q = p + 3;
    *q = 4;
    p = realloc(p,12*sizeof(int));
    *q = 5;                            //BOOM
}
```

Is there any way by which I can avoid the segmentation fault caused in `LINE 8` by automatically reallocating the intermediate pointer `q`?

Comment: Remember the offset from the beginning of the block to the pointed address, then recalculate the pointer after the `realloc`.

Comment: And your calculation of `q` is all wrong: the compiler will add "3 ints", so do not do "3*sizeof(int)" as that would be 12 ints (32 bit ints).

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie. But is there any library method which can remember the offset and then change it?

Comment: This issue should be avoided by using integer offsets instead of multiple pointers

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I would suggest fixing it to `q = p + 3;` since that bug distracts from the real question

Comment: `#define q (p + 3)`, ... use q, possibly move p, ... `#undef q`

Comment: Add more information to your question: What pointers do you have, and what do you know about them? In the example you show, `q` is simply `p+3`. In real code, will you always have a pointer at some fixed offset from the base? Those are easy to calculate. But, if you have pointers at varying locations and need to adjust them, that is more difficult. Given pointer to be adjusted `q`, old address `p0`, and new address `p1`, the new value for `q` would be `q - p0 + p1`. Unfortunately, `p0` generally becomes invalid when the memory is reallocated…

Comment: … Instead, you can record the offset with `ptrdiff_t qdiff = q - p0;`, then reallocate, then rebuild `q` with `q = p1 + qdiff;`. You would need to do that for each pointer you want to reallocate. So, if you have more than a few, some other approach to your code, such as just keeping offsets and not pointers, may be better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reassign the pointer `q` after reallocation the memory like

```
p = realloc(p,12*sizeof(int));
q = p + 3;

*q = 5;
```

Pay into account that you should use an intermediate pointer when you call the function realloc because in general it can return NULL. In this case there will be a memory leak.

For example

```
int *tmp = realloc(p,12*sizeof(int));

if ( tmp != NULL ) 
{
    p = tmp;
    q = p + 3;
}
```